# python xlwings | copy paste range with api, code ran non stop

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Hello I'm new to python and xlwings and this is my first question on stackoverflow : I use python3.8, xlwings 0.21.1 and pywin32-300 (latest version)
While using a simple code trying to copy a cell with format to another new created worksheet, my code seems to run non-stop at the line using api.copy
Does anybody know why ?

```
import xlwings as xw
workbook = xw.Book(r'my\file\path\myfile.xlsx')

def my_function():
    sht1 = workbook.sheets.add('Sheet1')
    sht = workbook.sheets[1]
    if sht.api.AutoFilterMode == True:
        sht.api.AutoFilterMode = False
    lr = sht.range('B' + str(sht.cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row

    sht.range('A8').api.copy
    sht1.activate()
    sht1.range('A8').api.select
    sht1.api.paste
    workbook.app.api.CutCopyMode=False
my_function()
```

Comment: I just ran your code and everything works fine. Also you dont need to reference the api you can just copy and paste directly like `sht.range('A8').copy()` then `sht1.range('A8').paste()`

Comment: @West, thanks for your response, I used api coz I wanted to copy paste with source formatting like strikethrough. I tested your suggestion and I found it also keeping the source formatting, so my probmem is solved ;)

Comment: Thats great., u welcome :)